# Can SOLR calculate and then query based on array position matches?

Tags: arrays, function, solr, predicate

In our SOLR documents, we store the contributor first and last names as two separate arrays, that correspond to one another, along with their role in the publication.

In this case, I'd like to write a query to run from our middleware platform that only returns documents in which authors that correspond to certain contributor codes. An example is here:

```
<arr name="Role">
  <str>Author</str>
  <str>Cover</str>
  <str>Author2</str>
  <str>Summary</str>
</arr>
<arr name="Forename">
  <str>George</str>
  <str>John</str>
  <str>George</str>
  <str>Sue</str>
</arr>
<arr name="Surname">
  <str>Anderson</str>
  <str>Smith</str>
  <str>Anderson</str>
  <str>Maryson</str>
</arr>
```

but the positions of the Role array items will vary with each document...

Here, I'd like only to query `Author` and `Author2`, i.e. Forename and Surname array positions 1 and 3 "George" and "Anderson", and ignore John Smith and Sue Maryson.

Is this possible at the query level?

Thanks